# How to get all product from a category including its subcategories in Magento?

Tags: magento

I'm looking for a way to retrieve all products from a category includings its subcategories and return me a Product Collection.

I know I can iterate over categories to get ids of product and load them in the view, but I would have liked to get a product collection as it is done currently in most categories/views.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved this problem by implementing addCategoriesFilter in product collection model, here is the patch. Modified code to be copied to the `local` pool to allow updates to a newer version.

```
@@ -103,6 +103,7 @@
      * Allowed filters
      *  store_id                int;
      *  category_id             int;
+     *  category_ids            array;
      *  category_is_anchor      int;
      *  visibility              array|int;
      *  website_ids             array|int;
@@ -567,6 +568,21 @@
     }

     /**
+     * Specify categories filter for product collection
+     *
+     * @param array $categories
+     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection
+     */
+    public function addCategoriesFilter(array $categories)
+    {
+        $this->_productLimitationFilters['category_ids'] = $categories;
+
+        ($this->getStoreId() == 0)? $this->_applyZeroStoreProductLimitations() : $this->_applyProductLimitations();
+
+        return $this;
+    }
+
+    /**
      * Join minimal price attribute to result
      *
      * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection
@@ -1592,7 +1608,7 @@
         $this->_productLimitationJoinPrice();
         $filters = $this->_productLimitationFilters;

-        if (!isset($filters['category_id']) && !isset($filters['visibility'])) {
+        if (!isset($filters['category_id']) && !isset($filters['category_ids']) && !isset($filters['visibility'])) {
             return $this;
         }

@@ -1604,11 +1620,16 @@
             $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()
                 ->quoteInto('cat_index.visibility IN(?)', $filters['visibility']);
         }
-        $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()
-            ->quoteInto('cat_index.category_id=?', $filters['category_id']);
-        if (isset($filters['category_is_anchor'])) {
+
+        if (!isset($filters['category_ids'])) {
             $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()
-                ->quoteInto('cat_index.is_parent=?', $filters['category_is_anchor']);
+                ->quoteInto('cat_index.category_id=?', $filters['category_id']);
+            if (isset($filters['category_is_anchor'])) {
+                $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()
+                    ->quoteInto('cat_index.is_parent=?', $filters['category_is_anchor']);
+            }
+        } else {
+            $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()->quoteInto('cat_index.category_id IN(' . implode(',', $filters['category_ids']) . ')', "");
         }

         $joinCond = join(' AND ', $conditions);
```

Usage:

```php
$category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
$categories = $category->getAllChildren(true);

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addCategoriesFilter($categories);
```

Comment: I actually did something similar and overrided the resource in my module to add such method, thank you.

Comment: `is_anchor` attribute is not enough to do the same ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to set that category to Anchor = Yes in de backend. That way your collection will nculde all the products form his subcategories.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to show all products assigned to a category below the root category of a store you could do the following (or replace root category with the one you desire):

```
$root_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
$all_cat_ids = explode(",", $root_category->getAllChildren());
$collection->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $all_cat_ids));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This almost works, it breaks if a product exists both in the current category and the child category since it tries to add the item to the collection twice.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the answer by Matt, but without the "XXX already exists" error.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
$app = Mage::app('admin');

$rootCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(17);
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$allCatIds = explode(",", $rootCategory->getAllChildren());
$collection
    ->getSelect()
    ->group('entity_id');
$collection
    ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $allCatIds));

echo $collection->count();
```

Comment: Where we need to add this!

Comment: @RajMohan this is a standalone script so in the web root

Comment: May i knw the file path and name of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the incomplete answer, but an approach that might work is to look at the category path for the parent (`1/2/3`) and use a query (on a category collection?) that grabs all descendents of that category (path like `1/2/3%`). Then, you could use that to filter a product collection. Maybe someone else can flesh out those details and answer better :)

Comment: hi, thank you, that's actually the first "smart" answer I can from around the web. i'm a bit new to work with Magento and collection, so may I ask you to tell me a bit more on how to customize a query of collection to add such where?