# Display New Products, Filter by Category Ids: in Magento

Tags: magento, collections, categories, product

i have magento 1.5 and i want to display new products Filter by Category Ids. I had try by `->addCategoryFilter($categoryId);`
 But not working...

I also try [this](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-filter-product-collection-using-2-or-more-category-filters/) tips, which exactly i want by (Category ids). but it give me error of: "Invalid attribute Category_ids"...

SO can any one display new products in magento by list of Category ids....?

Comment: @chapagain, How to do this..?

Comment: @Alan Storm, @Joseph Mastey, Please tell me what to do with this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my reply here [How to get all product from a category including its subcategories in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453493/how-to-get-all-product-from-a-category-including-its-subcategories-in-magento/6464870#6464870)

Comment: hi, i use your way.. that pass array of category ids to : $collection->addCategoriesFilter($categories);
but nothing happened.. i actually want to get new products from categories as a id  ( like  -> 3,5,6)..

Comment: do you have correct categories in $categories variable? can you see what query was generated? echo $collection->getSelect();

Comment: it give me: ->
SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`

Comment: seems filter is not applied, did you put modified collection model in the local pool? Could you show all the code you are using to get products collection?

Comment: i am using new.php code in catalog->product->new : and want to filter it by category ids.... and thanx for your replies..

Answer (score 0):

To filter with Category you need to pass category model data rather then category ID. As like 
below.

```
$category_id = 10;
$catagory_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
$collection->addCategoryFilter($catagory_model);
```

Please see this link for more detail http://way2discuss.blogspot.in/2012/07/magento-show-all-products-from-specific.html